# React Browser Error (MIME Type not Executable)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a basic tutorial for a react app and was hit with this error in the browser.

**"Refused to execute script from 
'http://localhost:8080/bundle.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."**

I cannot find any support online for this error and would like to understand what the problem is. I have spent about 2 hours trying to debug. One forum mentioned it was in-browser cookies but this was not the problem. I believe it may be something to do with my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ReactJS Sample Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you have any ideas! I am relatively new to coding and it is frustrating hitting a dead end so early in a project.

Comment: The local dev server you use is not sending correct mime types. What server do you use?

Comment: You have to enable "Cross Origin Resource Sharing" (CORS) in your server.

Comment: @ThananjayaChakravarthy — No! That's utter rubbish. The error message has nothing to do with CORS. The URLs in the code are all *same* origin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Tesseract.js in a React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088181/how-to-use-tesseract-js-in-a-react-app)

Answer (score 2):

The browser is asking the server to give it `bundle.js`.

Then the server is responding with "Here is `bundle.js`, it is an HTML document".

---

This means one of two things:

1. It is an HTML document (with an odd URL)
2. It is a JS file, but the server thinks that it is HTML

The first thing to do is to look at the data in the file. You could do this by looking at the Network tab in the developer tools in your browser.

If it is JS, then you need to fix your server so it sends the correct Content-Type header for JavaScript (`application/javascript`).

If it isn't JS, you need to figure out why. Possibly you have the wrong URL. Possibly the server isn't set up so it can serve your JS at all.

Whatever the problem, you will need to examine your HTTP server more than the client side code you shared in the question.

Comment: Hi Quentin,

Thank you for the reply I really appreciate the help!

I tried looking at the Network tab but it is empty.

I tried changing my script tag from text/javascript to application/javascript but it still gives the same error.

One thing I have noticed is that I don't have a webpack.config.js file being created and I am not sure why. For reference, I was following this demo https://codeburst.io/yet-another-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-a-react-project-part-1-bdc8a29aea22.

Once again apologize if my question is vague.

Comment: "I tried looking at the Network tab but it is empty". —‚ It needs to be open when the request is made (and not configured to hide the type of request you are looking for).

Comment: "I tried changing my script tag from text/javascript to application/javascript" — Leave the script tag alone. You need to look at the HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a single page HTML5 application then chances are the default server is configured to send index.html back for every resources not found instead of 404 to enable full page refresh for every virtual path in your application. Now if bundle.js is not present for any reason, then you get back a legitimate html response. You have to debug your application, or at least tell us more details about what you are using.

To debug your application, open the developer tools, go to the network panel, and refresh the page to see the resources being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears to occur when a package manager like npm is used. The following stack overflow answer solved the problem for me. You need to just use the CDN link to the library using  tag.

[How to use Tesseract.js in a React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47088181/how-to-use-tesseract-js-in-a-react-app/47372686)

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Network tab in Developer tools and look at the error (might be in the Headers tab within Network) what URL do you see that it is attempting to obtain the bundle.js file from.  The answer may be as simple prefixing bundle.js with a slash (i.e. src="/bundle.js") if you are using client-side routing.